# Crop image ( big image have size >200 kb ) not correctly in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, image, jpeg

I'm searched many time for this problem but did not get a correct answer. I want to crop x, y, right, bottom of the image by condition that i want (i open it in paint software and get x, y , width, height that i want.) I cropped it follow x, y, right, bottom then it crop correctly but when i got a problem when i crop big image ( size image > 200 kb ). It crop not correctly. I don't know why it work wrong.
Can anyone help me for resolve it. Thank you so much !
This is my code :

```
Dim sh as shape
Dim shpCrop As Shape
Dim sngMemoLeft As Double
Dim sngMemoTop As Double
Dim crLeft As Double
Dim crTop As Double
Dim crBottom As Double
Dim crRight As Double

Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
        fileName:=strPathFileImg, _
        linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
        left:=65, top:=50, width:=1300, height:=755

crLeft = (x_Crop ) * 0.75
crTop = (y_Crop ) * 0.75
crBottom = (bottom_Crop ) * 0.75
crRight = (right_Crop ) * 0.75

'Trim img
Set shpCrop = ActiveSheet.Shapes(sh.name)
With shpCrop
    sngMemoLeft = .left
    sngMemoTop = .top
    With .PictureFormat
        .CropLeft = crLeft
        .CropTop = crTop
        .CropBottom = crBottom
        .CropRight = crRight
    End With
    .left = sngMemoLeft
    .top = sngMemoTop
End With
```

Comment: You are aware that Excel measures in `Point`, not `Pixel`?

Comment: Yes. i know that. i convert pixel to point before i crop it. You can see my code above. thanks !